# I have a Ph.D. in Educational Science from Iran. Do I need accreditation to work in the U.S.?

Tags: academic-life

I have a Ph.D. in Educational Science from Iran. Do I need accreditation to work in the U.S.?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Can you please clarify for what kind of work you may need accreditation?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "_work in the U.S_". Teaching in a university/college? Teaching at a K-12 school? Work for an NGO? Work for a private company?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to be certified if you wanted to teach in the public schools (kindergarten through twelfth grade).  But there isn't anything like this for teaching in college.  It's just a matter of convincing the department that you're the right person for the job, based on your qualifications.

**Edit:**  I tried to make my first sentence clearer.

Comment: It's worth noting that "you would need to be certified to teach in the public schools" applies only to people who wish to teach in these schools.  One can teach in an education school at the college level (teaching future K-12 teachers) without actually holding the certification necessary to be a K-12 teacher.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician - see Answer's first sentence, edited to prevent this misunderstanding.